# django force form is_valid

Tags: python, django, forms

i would like to force my_form.is_valid() to return a valid response when my form have a checked box to True. But everytime is not valid...

```
def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get("replay_transaction") == True:
        #what i need to do to ignore all other field verification (card number, cvv, ...)?
    else:
        self.cleaned_data
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a custom function that validates the fields and call it instead of form.is_valid()

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning